# How can Webrick based (Non RoR, Sinatra) web application can be severed using Apache and Passenger?

Tags: ruby, passenger, rack, webrick

I have developed a small ruby web application using Webrick abstract servlet , File-handler and basic authentication. Now I want this application to be served using apache and passenger, what are the options available

1. Do I need to remove Webrick dependent code and use sinatra or rack?

   0r
2. Any other short cut is available like writing a rackup, etc ?

Comment: if it a rack means there exists `.ru` file app then deployment using thin,passenger or unicorn can work with ease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your application WITH Webrick served by Apache you don't need Passenger
use mod_proxy in Apache with ProxyPass* primitives

If you want  Apache + Passenger you have to change Webrick against Rack or Passenger compatible, Merb, Rails, etc...

Comment: thanks Romain for clarification, Finally, I chose for first option changing webrick with sinatra. Now, i am able to deploy it with passenger.